# C++, recoursive #include

Tags: c++

I have a following problem:

I have two classes, class no 2 includes an array of objects class no 2 type. Furthermore i need do write a function of class no 2  which would be a friend to class no 1. Something like this:

class1.h :

```
    class Class1{
    ...
    friend void Class2::foo();
    }
```

class2.h:

```
    %include "class1.h"

    class Class2{

    ...
    Class1 * array[10];
    void foo()
    }
```

The problem is, that in definition of class1, the program dosent recognize yet class2. I cant include class2.h in class1.h, because I would create recoursive inclusion. Any ideas?

Comment: Please put a little more effort into your question, like spelling "#include" correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Use [forward declaration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration#Classes):

- In file class2.h, change `#include "class1.h"` to `class Class1;`
- In file class2.cpp, add `#include "class1.h"`

---

You can do this, because `Class2` uses a pointer (not an instance) of `Class1`.

Comment: Thanks a lot .
I tried it, but the other way around,  forward declaration of class2 in class1.h file :)

Comment: @KarolŻurowski: You're welcome :) As long as no actual instance of `Class1` is used within `Class2`, there's no actual need to include the header of `Class1`, since the size and memory layout of this class does not affect the size and memory layout of `Class2`. The pointer is just a pointer - it has a well known size (typically 4 or 8 bytes), and the compiler can infer the size and memory layout of `Class2` without knowing any further details about `Class1`.